# Android: Logcat]device not found on running Google's sample Notepad app

Tags: android, android-emulator, logcat

I opened my NotepadCodeLab, NotepadAdv1 project, and got this as soon as I built and ran:

```
[2010-11-01 14:42:48 - DeviceMonitor]Sending jdwp tracking request failed!
[2010-11-01 14:42:48 - Logcat]device not found
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:736)
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:373)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:285)
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogPanel$3.run(LogPanel.java:516)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Check this out [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484636/android-device-debug-stopped-after-plug-other-phone][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484636/android-device-debug-stopped-after-plug-other-phone

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bizarrely, when I came back the next day (after restarting Eclipse/my computer), it worked. Should have tried that first. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

Emulator or physical device?  If emulator, is it already running?  If it's a device, is it connected via USB?

Assuming you have the SDK installed and on your path, if you type "adb devices" into the command prompt, your device should show up.  If it doesn't, follow the SDK installation instructions here:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a real device, don't forget the USB driver.  You also have to have installed into your SDK and AVD manager the correct version for your phone.  If you were upgraded to v2.2, also install v2.1.