# Android Device Debug stopped after plug other phone

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, device, apk

I've launched and debugged several applications on my Samsung Galaxy S Device,
however, yesterday I plugged in another Device (Same type) to upload music
and now, when I try to launch or debug application, Eclipse wants me to
choose between 2 devices (only 1 is online), and when I select this option,
I'm getting the following Error log:

```
[2011-03-30 11:36:56 - ****] Uploading ****.apk onto device '1000b1eda2c2'
[2011-03-30 11:36:56 - ****] Failed to install ****.apk on device '1000b1eda2c2': adb rejected install command with: device offline
[2011-03-30 11:36:56 - ****] com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device offline
[2011-03-30 11:36:56 - ****] Launch canceled!
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try "adb kill-server" and then "adb start-server"

Comment: where can i find this options?

Comment: depends on your operation system. adb.sh oder adb.exe can be found in your android sdk folder. Start a shell/command line, go to the sdk folder an run this commands.

Comment: adb has been moved to android-sdk\platform-tools